# export html form to pdf

Tags: php, html, export

I have created an html form with a number of fields and I want to export the page to pdf.
The html code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<form action="myphpfile.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Download as pdf!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have got the php code to export the form to pdf from http://freehtmltopdf.com/ but whenever I click on the"Download as pdf" button it simply shows me the php code in the file. I have my webserver running on XAMP and the html file is in htdocs. I need further help in converting this html to pdf.

The php code I got from the site is:

```
<?php

    $url = 'http://freehtmltopdf.com';
    $data = array(  'convert' => '', 
            'html' => '<html><head><title>My Title</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="relativepath.css"></head><body><h1>Web Page</h1><p>This is my content.</p></body></html>',
            'baseurl' => 'http://www.myhost.com');

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    // set the pdf data as download content:
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="webpage.pdf"');
    echo($result);

?>
```

Comment: I am not sure about `echo($result);` part. What happens when you remove it?

Comment: The code is correct and supposed to create the PDF file without problems. However, you have a problem about PHP in your server. Your server doesn't execute PHP files. Therefore you need to focus on fixing this part first. As I said, the code is correct.

Comment: I tested your code and also gave a link here but I can't keep a link that will be dead in SO and you didn't show up in its lifetime. Just to let you know - PHP is likely not enabled in your server. Perhaps you didn't restart your server after installation or something like that. Go to your Apache logs and see what is wrong.

Comment: Try using FPDF on converting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) for your problem.

Sample is here below:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>How to create Contact Form</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .header {
        color: #36A0FF;
        font-size: 27px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Convert HTML to PDF in PHP with fpdf</h1>
</div>
<!-- Contact Form - START -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="well well-sm">
//action page where pdf will be create and shown into the browser
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="createpdf.php">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend class="text-center header" style="width:70%;">Contact us<span><img src="images/logo.png"></span></legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                               <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="col-md-8">

                                <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Contact Form - END -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my php is.

**createpdf.php**

```
<?php
require('WriteHTML.php');
$pdf=new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();

////add page page automatically for its true parameter

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 15);
$pdf->AddPage();
//add images or logo which you want
$pdf->Image('images/logo.png',18,13,33);
//set font style
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$pdf->WriteHTML('<para><h1>Click4Knowledge Web Programming Blog, Tutorials, jQuery, Ajax, PHP, MySQL and Demos</h1><br>
Website: <u>www.click4knowledge.com</u></para><br><br>How to Convert HTML to PDF with fpdf example');

//set the form of pdf

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7);

//assign the form post value in a variable and pass it.

$htmlTable='<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD>Name:</TD>
<TD>'.$_POST['name'].'</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Email:</TD>
<TD>'.$_POST['email'].'</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Phone:</TD>
<TD>'.$_POST['phone'].'</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>';
//Write HTML to pdf file and output that file on the web browser.
$pdf->WriteHTML2("<br><br><br>$htmlTable");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',6);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Modify this sample for you to able to produce the output you like.

Comment: How do I run this on my browser? I need help with that. As I said, I have a XAMPP server running, can you help me on how to run this?